# Filmic Blender not working

Tags: color-management, filmic-blender

I have been using Filmic Blender for months now, and it has been working perfectly. But today, when I tried to switched to Filmic, this is what showed up:
[image: Scene>Color Management>render>view>View Transform]

- I have Blender 2.78
- I have not done anything to my settings besides downloading Archimesh and turned off mipmapping
- I have not updated the plugin

In the Colormanagement folder in the Blender folder, it shows that it is installed correctly:
[image: Colormangement]

Comment: seems to me that you are posting in this site regularly, so please understand that in order to help you, we can only go by the information you provide. Please spend a bit more time and effort on your questions.  [Edit] your question and add detail on how you installed the filmic configuration. Did you upgrade to a different version of blender but did not change the color management for the new one? Are you getting any errors on the console?  We have no way to know what changed between the last time that your settings worked and today other than the information you share.

Comment: @cegaton That is the weird thing... It used to work perfectly and I have not down anything that would affect it...

Comment: Download again from [github](https://github.com/sobotka/filmic-blender) and  replace the colorm anagement folder following the instructions on the page.

Comment: This seems like a really weird problem.  I suspect hard-drive file corruption, or you had filmic setting on a hotkey, and you accidentally assigned that hotkey to something else.

Comment: @TeaCrab My computer is state-of-the-art! Plus, nothing has happened to any of my other files

Comment: @YusaMac205, consider yourself experiencing a problem that no one has ever experienced.  Good luck finding answers.  I suggest you install another Blender app in a different folder, and see if Filmic works.

Comment: @YusaMac205 - Do you have multiple Blender version installs?  Have you tried (as cegaton suggested) reinstalling Filmic?

Comment: How about trying a daily build from builder.blender.org? Blender 2.79 has Filmic built in.

Comment: @dr.Sybren I am only finding 2.78 test builds...

Comment: They are called 2.78 until 2.79 has been released.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating your Blender will automatically add a working filmic. I still don't understand why it isn't working on 2.78. If you lose some of your projects by updating, please understand that you can have more than one Blender on your device.

Answer (score 0):

The current version is 2.79. So it has the Filmic incorporated in it. No need to install it. 
This question is relevant now.

Comment: Thanks, this is an old question. I do currently do have Blender 2.79. I was just answering it for other people, and because I couldn't delete the question. I am trying to get my privilege of asking questions back